# swift4で【●Ambiguous use of 'dispatch_get_main_queue()'】とエラーが出てしまいます。

Tags: swift4

```
func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data,
    fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {   ●Ambiguous use of 'dispatch_get_main_queue()'

        //テキストフィールドの更新(8)
        self.updateTextField(self.data2str(data)!)
    })
}
```

エラーの解決方法を教えて下さい。
初心者なのでさっぱりわかりません。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644492/ambiguous-use-of-dispatchqueue-on-trying-to-use-main-thread

にある通り

Swift3から

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

})
```

と書きます。
Swift4でも同様となります。